# Eclipse - files open with no tab title or and empty content window

Tags: eclipse, file

I just installed Eclipse on a computer and it has been working fine for the past few days. However it suddenly stopped working this morning.

When I double click a file in the File Explorer to open it, nothing happens - a new tab is opened, but the tab has no title, just a button to close the tab. The "contents" of the tab is just a light blue screen, with no text.

I have tried the following procedures, with no success:

1. Right click > Open with > various Eclipse editor
2. Reset perspective (I am in Java EE perspective)
3. Change perspective to Java
4. Opening different file formats (.java, .properties, .xml, etc)
5. F3 and Ctrl-Shift-T
6. Creating a new project and opening a file from there
7. Restarting, cleaning workspace

When I open a different workspace, the files open as usual, but I still want to use my old workspace.

I am using Eclipse JEE Oxygen.

Comment: What do you mean by _"cleaning workspace"_? Starting Eclipse with the option `-clean`? Which plug-ins do you have installed? Are there some errors logged in the _Error Log_ view?

Comment: I have Aptana plugin and git plugin. Clean means Project tab > clean. There are no errors in markers view, I don't know how to get to error log.

Comment: Try to start Eclipse from the command line with the option `-clean`. If this does not help, maybe you will find more details about the problem in _Window > Show View > Error Log_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a re-install fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a new workspace and put all your projects there from the old one. 
If it does not work, it's likely that there is an error in one of the projects, try to find it, delete the project from the new workspace 1 and try to open the file, repeat it until the file opens, if you make a mistake in 1 of the projects, then you can create new classes. and copy there codes from the old ones.
P. S. If nothing works, you can download [INTELIJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) and open your workspace there (generally Intelij is more comfortable than Eclipse in my opinion)